# Play Framework 2: How to access default values for hidden form fields in view templates?

Tags: java, forms, playframework-2.2

I assuming this will be a rather quick and possibly embarrassingly easy answer. I have been racking my brains and no amount of internet searches seem to turn up possible solutions. I am using the Play framework 2.2. To set the question up, I have constructed a simple "online college registration form" example which a student completes.

In our models, we are using Ebean. The following classes show the relationships, i.e. one college has many students.

```
@Entity
public class College extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  @OneTOMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  public List<Student> Student;

  public College(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  // all other variables and methods for College class
}

@Entity
public class Student extends Model {
  @Id
  public Long id = id;
  public String name;
  @ManyToOne
  public College college;

  public Student(College college) {
    this.college = college
  }

  // all other variables and methods for Student class
}
```

In the Controller index method, we instantiate our form. We are assuming we know which college the student will be attending and want to set that as a default hidden value in the form. The intention is to render the student form and pass it back in the response.

```
Form<Student> form = Form.form(Student.class);
College college = new College("My College");
form.fill(new Student(college));
return ok(student.render(form));
```

Lastly and on to the question, considering the classes involved, while rendering the view how would one set a hidden field with these default values? And why is there no hidden field helper I wonder...

```
@(studentForm: play.data.Form[Student])
...
@form(routes.Students.create()) {
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="college.id" value="???">
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alright, after much hair loss I finally figured out what the problem was. Initially, as biesior rightly suggested I used `@(studentForm("college.id").value)`, however since this was not working I figured I must be doing wrong... and yes, there was, however it was not in the view, it was in the controller. If we add: `form = form.fill(new Student(college))` Then it works like a dream. Silly mistake. Since biesior was 100% correct I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
@(studentForm: play.data.Form[Student])

<input type="hidden" name="college.id" value='@(studentForm("college.id").value)'>
```

BTW, try to avoid using `form` word for name of your param, it's quite easy to produce name clash ie. with `@helper` import... instead consider as a rule of thumb using names like `studentForm` - it will be always clean, which param you are referring atm.

Comment: Appreciate the input. haha, embarrassing, yes I do name my form variables appropriately however something must have gotten lost during the cut&paste while creating the example. I was doing as you suggested however for some silly reason when I check the chrome console (as its loaded into the page via a jquery AJAX call) it outputs `<input type="hidden" name="college.id" value>` it is driving me meeental.